# Xamarin IOS/Android DOTMIM SYNC compatible with Azure Sql

Tags: database, sqlite, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, data-synchronization

I have an Xamarin cross platform application.  I am currently storing my data in a Sqlite Database.  However we want to have bi-directional syncing with an Azure Sql Database.  After much reading I decided to give Dotmim Sync a try.  The initial sync worked, however when adding a column to a table and attempting to migrate the data (following the tutorial), I got an error stating that the tracking table was missing.  I redid everything again and realized that the entity tracking table was never created and I am not sure why.  However Sql created a tracking table but it was not the entity tracking table that the error stated was missing.

I am curious if anyone with Xamarin has been able to successfully create bi-directional syncing with Sqlite and Azure Sql using Dotmim Sync.  I have yet to find anything else that will work.  Other than hand jamming it in this tutorial:  https://www.xamarinhelp.com/mobile-database-bi-directional-synchronization-rest-api/

I am not against that, just seems like a lot of room for error.  I am hoping someone out there has had success with what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm using Dotmim sync to synchronize a Sql Server database with a Sqlite database hotsted in a xamarin forms application through an API.
I think that I had the same problem as yours.
The problem is, as far as I understood, that the tracking tables are created only on the first sync.
If you change the schema of those tables you will need to call the Deprovision method.
This method will re-create the stored procedures and the triggers with the new database schema.
I'll leave you the link to the docs:
https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/Provision.html#provision-deprovision.

Comment: I tried the Dotmim Deprovision but with no success.  I spent weeks trying to figure the issue out.  The creator of Dotmim was too busy to be of much assistance.  I found a very simple hand jammed sync example in Github that was exactly what I needed.  I expanded on it and it works perfect for what I need.